# Extend (python's) jsonschema module to allow specification of non-primitive property types

Tags: python, jsonschema

I have a situation where I want a series of modular components to express their parameter requirements via an inline jsonschema definition, held within the code as an attribute containing a dict in which a jsonschema definition is stored. This is used to validate inputs at runtime, but also is used to build a UI at design/specification time.

Most of the time, the parameter requirements fit neatly into the vanilla `string`, `number`, `object` sub-categories as defined by normal jsonschema - but on occasion I want to specify that a particular property be a very particular python datatype - maybe `pandas.DataFrame`, `numpy.ndarray`, or `MyClass`.

Clearly, I'm pushing what would normally be expected of a json schema document, but this feels as though it's something that might be useful, and I was wondering if and whether this extension of the core set of datatypes was possible - and if so, how to go about defining something along those lines.

```
{ "title" : "Named DataFrame", 
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
      "name" : {      "type" : "string",
                      "description" : "Name of a dataframe"},
      "dataframe" : { "description" : "A pandas.DataFrame object", 
                      "type" : pandas.DataFrame }
                },
"additionalProperties" : "false"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the object responsible for this extensibility is [jsonschema.TypeChecker](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validate/#validating-with-additional-types).